# precompiled header .pch files are machine sensitive?

Tags: c++, build, visual-c++, precompiled-headers

I tried to reuse the .pch to speed the build using the following way:

1. use /Yc on stdafx.cpp to create the .pch files to a folder
2. exclude stdafx.cpp in the project, and modify the link option

It success in my machine, but failed in another, got the error message: error C2011: '***' : 'struct' type redefinition

So first I want to ask whether the .pch files are machine sensitive? then secondly, the above approaches workable?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to indicate compiler... I'm assuming Visual C++, given that you are using that nasty "stdafx" header file that Visual C++ forces on you (and everyone else).

Comment: It's indeed VC++; the error code is recognizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precompiled headers can be machine specific up to Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/11/12/visual-c-precompiled-header-errors-on-windows-7.aspx)):

> Precompiled header files store the
>   “state” of a compilation up to a
>   certain point, and that state
>   information can be reused in
>   subsequent compiler invocations to
>   significantly increase build
>   throughput. For the past 15 years, our
>   compiler has persisted precompiled
>   headers to disk and reloaded them
>   directly into virtual memory with
>   99.999% reliability and considerable performance gains. The tradeoff,
>   however, was a degree of fragility in
>   our architecture.
>
> Since the PCH file itself contains
>   internal pointers, **it must be loaded
>   at the exact same address in virtual
>   memory where it was created**.